# Get finer grid - Python

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I wanna have a 5x5 grid of movable points.
Those form a maybe pillow kinda shape. I want the splines to be cubic.
Then i wanna fit a way finer grid, like 100x50, in that.
I dont want to interpolate any values but to know where the finer grid would be in x-y.

Has anyone ever done something like this? Is there a way to interpolate a finer grid in a rougher one?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything till now?

Comment: So i have the movable points going. I already asked this question but was misunderstood i guess. I had someone answer with scipy.interpolate.interp2d but idk how to do it without z values. I dont need them, i just the x and y.

So no, i dont have anything remarkable to share yet